# php image optimize from database using mysqli

Tags: php, image, compression

I am trying to compress all images from my database, each image called from the database is represented by the variable $oldImage which then compresses it and replaces the image in the same folder with the same name (currently works if i put same image_name.jpg in each of $source_img and $compress_img. This is my current code:

```
<?

include "database.php";
         $raw_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products") or 
die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
?>

<?php 

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
}

$oldImage = $results['img'];

$source_img = "../img/products/$oldImage";
$destination_img = "../img/products/$oldImage";

$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);

?>

<?
  }

   }else{
            echo "No results";
        }

?>
```

The $oldImage variable is get the name of the image correctly for the first one but then stops because of this error:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare compress() (previously declared in /home/www/********.co.uk/*****/compress.php:19) in /home/www/********/*****/compress.php on line 19

Comment: Move your `function compress(){...}` declaration OUTSIDE of the `while` loop. Its a very basic syntax mistake, and I vote to close.

Comment: Dam! thank you @IncredibleHat blonde moment